# Exception in adding document in SolrJ

Tags: solr

I am building a java application using solrj. When i add document for a single record, program runs fine. When i use Collection, at server.add(docs) i get the following exception:   " Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request

Bad Request

request: http://localhost:8080/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=1 " When i debug the program, i see that documents are added to Collection docs object.

Let me know to clarify something.

Regards,

Ankit Agarwal

Comment: check the Solr log and post the full exception.

Answer (score 3):

Check your schema xml and ensure that you dont add any field not declared in your schema file. Also check whether "id" field is available for every document and declared in the schema.